# Why an application keeps opening new threads instead of reusing ones from pool

Tags: .net, multithreading, windbg

I have a windows service which runs database tasks in a separate thread (more detailed description in [How to diagnose why a Threadstatic connection is not garbage collected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47093041)). The service is supposed to run only one background thread at a time. It was observed that the service does not releases resources (especially database connections) properly. I have analysed memory dumps and there is increasing number of idle threads:

```
!ThreadPool
CPU utilization: 0%
Worker Thread: Total: 65 Running: 0 Idle: 65 MaxLimit: 1023 MinLimit: 4
Work Request in Queue: 0
--------------------------------------
Number of Timers: 1
--------------------------------------
Completion Port Thread:Total: 1 Free: 1 MaxFree: 8 CurrentLimit: 1 MaxLimit: 1000 MinLimit: 4
```

Thread list(shortened):

```
!threads
ThreadCount:      80
UnstartedThread:  0
BackgroundThread: 70
PendingThread:    0
DeadThread:       8
Hosted Runtime:   no
                                                                         Lock  
       ID OSID ThreadOBJ    State GC Mode     GC Alloc Context  Domain   Count Apt Exception
   0    1 34e8 005c0d98     2a020 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 005bb308 0     MTA 
   2    2 1308 005ce540     2b220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 005bb308 0     MTA (Finalizer) 
   3    6 2580 00659908   102a220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 005bb308 0     MTA (Threadpool Worker) 
   5    7 1130 00698cc8   202b020 Preemptive  100EFE68:00000000 005bb308 0     MTA 
   8   10 3540 04133f00   202b220 Preemptive  0FE8EFC4:00000000 005bb308 1     MTA 
  11   20 3518 09253c30   1020220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 005bb308 0     Ukn (Threadpool Worker) 
  12   14 44e4 0dc8e5c0   1029220 Preemptive  0FE8EA6C:00000000 005bb308 0     MTA (Threadpool Worker) 
  13    9 3bfc 0dc8eb08   1029220 Preemptive  0FE40EA4:00000000 005bb308 0     MTA (Threadpool Worker) 
  14   16 4328 04133470   1029220 Preemptive  0FF6CEA4:00000000 005bb308 0     MTA (Threadpool Worker) 
.....
 75   73 3b78 0e93a5b0   1029220 Preemptive  100973E0:00000000 005bb308 0     MTA (Threadpool Worker) 
  76   74 2ab4 0e93c018   1029220 Preemptive  10056368:00000000 005bb308 0     MTA (Threadpool Worker) 
XXXX   90    0 0de36520     39820 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 005bb308 0     Ukn 
XXXX   78    0 0e93aaf8   8039820 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 005bb308 0     Ukn (Threadpool Completion Port) 
XXXX   77    0 1106fa78     39820 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 005bb308 0     Ukn 
XXXX   75    0 0e93b588     39820 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 005bb308 0     Ukn 
XXXX   76    0 10d53a78     39820 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 005bb308 0     Ukn 
XXXX   80    0 0e93d538     39820 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 005bb308 0     Ukn 
  77   82 2040 1106dac8   8029220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 005bb308 0     MTA (Threadpool Completion Port) 
XXXX   86    0 1106e010     39820 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 005bb308 0     Ukn 
XXXX   89    0 041339b8     39820 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 005bb308 0     Ukn
```

Thread stacks most of the threads seems to be the same:

```
~70kB
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
00 1247fbf4 75492cc7 00000268 00000000 1247fc3c ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc
01 1247fc68 748c2396 00000268 00004e20 00000000 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x99
02 1247fccc 748c25e7 00004e20 00000000 0e93caa8 clr!CLRSemaphore::Wait+0xc0
03 1247fd08 748c2681 00004e20 0a7a6632 748c1fe0 clr!ThreadpoolMgr::UnfairSemaphore::Wait+0x132
04 1247fd74 748d5dd1 00000000 748d5db7 748d5d80 clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart+0x389
05 1247fd90 76cf7c04 005f7c48 76cf7be0 08601cd5 clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x55
06 1247fda4 778cad2f 005f7c48 0929786d 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
07 1247fdec 778cacfa ffffffff 778b00a2 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
08 1247fdfc 00000000 748d5d80 005f7c48 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
```

Which as far as I now are threads waiting in the pool.
**Is there any way to continue analysis? Are the threads blocked somehow?**

Comment: @ThomasWeller: I am debugging an application whose concept is about 15 years old, but nevertheless I don't know how to persuade .net framework not to use thread pool.

Comment: Persuade it like this: use `new Thread()` instead of `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()`. Have you tried limiting the amount of ThreadPool threads? Curently it seems to be at 1024.

Comment: @ThomasWeller: new Thread() is used. Look at the code in the linked question, please. My interpretation is that framework is pooling without being explicitly required (I saw an article somewhere).

Comment: No, that code does not cause this behavior. Have you searched all your code, including (3rd party) libraries? Also look for TPL usage, BackgroundWorker, BeginInvoke calls, `Task.Factory.StartNew()`, `await` and `ContinueWith`.  If you can't find anything, I guess you need to `sxe ct` and see where the threads get created.

Comment: @ThomasWeller: The code does not use any `await` or `Task.Factory`. From time coincidence I suppose that there is no third party library to be blamed.  Problems are observed in production environment only with frequency 0 - 10 per day (from ~10k runs). I would prefer some diagnostics why the threads continue waiting to diagnosing when (why) they are created. The threads continue waiting for days (not minutes as I would suppose).

Comment: Ok, well, the argument to WaitForSingleObject is a handle. Use `!handle` to find out the type.

Comment: @ThomasWeller: For presented thread stack I run `!handle 268`. But the response is `Unable to read handle information`. Do you have an idea what can be wrong? The dump should contain handles for sure (`.dumpdebug` contains `0004 MiniDumpWithHandleData`). I have x86 process, x86 debugger and the dump was created by x86 Task Manager (the operating system is x64).